# Hide SwiftUI DisclosureGroup Arrow and Remove Default Padding

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a fully custom list of expandable sections that have projects inside them in SwiftUI. This is how I want it to look in the end:

[image]

I think I have the SwiftUI code set up right, but I'm having trouble finding view modifiers to accomplish what I want.

Here is my code with most style modifiers removed for brevity:

```
List {
  ForEach(sections, id: \.self) { section in
  
    DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $expand) {
      ForEach(section.projectArray, id: \.self) { project in
        //--- Projects ---
        HStack{
          Image("project")
          Text(project.wrappedName)
          Spacer()
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom:0, trailing: 0))
      } 
    } label: {
      //--- Sections ---
      HStack{
        Text(section.wrappedName)
        Spacer()
        //Custom Toggle Arrow
        Button(action: {
          //Toggle logic
        }){
          if expand{
            Image("section-open")
          }else{
            Image("section-closed")
          }
        }
      }
      .padding(0)
    }
  } 
}.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

I can't find anything to change `DisclosureGroup` that adds a few default styles I don't want:

**`A`** - A default expand/collapse arrow

**`B`** - When expanded, the `DisclosureGroup`'s `label` grows horizontally

**`C`** - Default padding on the child elements

[image]

I checked [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup) and don't see a way to remove these default styles. Any ideas how I can pull off this design?

Comment: The only solution I've found is to build your own list from scratch. This requires managing the state of each expand/collapse section yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Try to set `listRowInsets`'s leading minus 8 for your `DisclosureGroup`'s content

```
List {
    ForEach(sections) { section in
        DisclosureGroup {
            ForEach(section.items) {

            }.listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: -8, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        } label: { 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For iOS 16+ use [DisclosureGroupStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroupstyle) :

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomDisclosureGroupStyle<Label: View>: DisclosureGroupStyle {
    let button: Label
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                configuration.label
                Spacer()
                button
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    configuration.isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            }
            if configuration.isExpanded {
                configuration.content
                    .disclosureGroupStyle(self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a replacement for `DisclosureGroup` that allows customisation of the toggle image, size & color dynamically according to `isExpanded`:

```
/// Toggle Expand-Collapse section with:
/// * Label - header ending with Image button
/// * Image button - customisable expand-collapse toggle control
/// * Content - whatever you want to contain (expand to show, collapse to hide)
///
/// NOTE:
/// * Works with both 'ForEach {' and 'List { ForEach {' as Content.
/// * If a List is used, expands downwards to fill remainder of screen.
/// * If no List is used, expands just large enough to fit content height.
struct ExpandCollapse<Content: View, Label: View>: View {
    
    typealias makeContent = () -> Content
    typealias makeLabel = () -> Label
    
    typealias dynamicImageColor = (Bool) -> Color
    typealias dynamicRotation = (Bool) -> Double
    typealias dynamicSystemName = (Bool) -> String
    
    @Binding var isExpanded: Bool
    
    @ViewBuilder var content: makeContent
    @ViewBuilder var label: makeLabel
    
    let imageSize: CGFloat
    let imageRotation: dynamicRotation
    let imageColor: dynamicImageColor
    let imageName: dynamicSystemName
    
    init(
        isExpanded: Binding<Bool>,
        content: @escaping makeContent,
        label: @escaping makeLabel,
        imageSize: CGFloat = 18,
        imageColor: @escaping dynamicImageColor = { isExpanded in isExpanded ? Color.blue: Color.red },
        imageRotation: @escaping dynamicRotation = { _ in 0 },
        imageName: @escaping dynamicSystemName = { isExpanded in isExpanded ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down" }
    ) {
        _isExpanded = isExpanded
        self.content = content
        self.label = label
        
        self.imageSize = imageSize
        self.imageColor = imageColor
        self.imageRotation = imageRotation
        self.imageName = imageName
    }
    
    var expandCollapseButton: some View {
        Image(systemName: imageName(isExpanded))
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize, alignment: .center)
            .foregroundColor(imageColor(isExpanded))
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(imageRotation(isExpanded)))
            .pad(left: 5, right: 10)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isExpanded, content: content, label: label)
        .disclosureGroupStyle(CustomDisclosureGroupStyle(button: expandCollapseButton))
    }
}
```

The definition for `.pad` is:

```
import SwiftUI

@inlinable func insets(top: CGFloat = 0,
                       bot bottom: CGFloat = 0,
                       left leading: CGFloat = 0,
                       right trailing: CGFloat = 0) -> EdgeInsets {
    EdgeInsets(top: top, leading: leading, bottom: bottom, trailing: trailing)
}

extension View {
    
    @inlinable func pad(top: CGFloat = 0,
                        bot: CGFloat = 0,
                        left: CGFloat = 0,
                        right: CGFloat = 0) -> some View {
        self.padding(insets(top: top, bot: bot, left: left, right: right))
    }
    
    @inlinable func zeropad() -> some View { pad() }
}

extension EdgeInsets {
    static let zero = insets()
}
```

Example usage:

```
struct SimpleExampleView<T: MyData>: View {

    @State isExpanded: Bool
    @Binding items: [T]

    func buildRow(item: T) -> some view { Text(item.title) }

    var body: some View {
        ExpandCollapse(isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
            //List { // uncomment this & others to use List variant
                ForEach($items) { index, item in
                    self.buildRow(item: item)
                    //.listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                }
            //}.listStyle(.plain)
        } label: {
            Text("\(items.count) Items")
        }
    }
```

With the example run as shown above, the `ExpandCollapse` will expand just enough to fit its content height.

Alternatively, you can uncomment the indicated lines so a `List` is used. Then the `ExpandCollapse` will expand downwards to fill the remainder of the screen. This produces as large an area as possible for list interaction such as drag 'n' drop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky way which won't work inside `List` but it will work inside `LazyVStack` and other stacks.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isExpanded: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                DisclosureGroup("Disclosure", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                        .padding()
                }
                .buttonStyle(DisclosureStyle(isExpanded: $isExpanded))

            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}

struct DisclosureStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Binding var isExpanded: Bool
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: isExpanded ? "chevron.down.circle" : "chevron.right.circle")
                .if(configuration.isPressed) { image in
                    image.symbolVariant(.fill)
                }
                .foregroundStyle(isExpanded ? .green : .accentColor)
            Spacer()
            let font = isExpanded ? Font.headline.monospaced() : .headline
            configuration.label
                .font(font).id(font)
                .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                    Rectangle().fill(.bar).frame(maxWidth: 30)
            }
            .foregroundStyle(isExpanded ? .green : .accentColor)
        }
        .background(.bar)
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Custom DisclosureGroup]